# Count Child Elements within a List of Parent Elements in cshtml View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a cshtml view with a model of type `CategoryModel`. Within the view I need to count all of the items within the model. I would like to do this as succinctly as possible, preferrably without using a for loop. Is there a better way to do this or is the below code my best option?

#### Models cs

```cs
    public class CategoryModel
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public List<ItemGroupModel> ItemGroups { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemGroupModel
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public List<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemModel
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
    }
```

#### Current Solution

```cs
@{
    var itemGroupItemsCount = 0;
    if (CategoryModel.ItemGroups.Any())
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < CategoryModel.ItemGroups.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CategoryModel.ItemGroups[i].Items.Any())
            {
                itemGroupItemsCount += CategoryModel.ItemGroups[i].Items.Count;
            }
        }
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Linq you could do this:

```
var itemGroupItemsCount = CategoryModel.ItemGroups.Sum(i => i.Items.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is

```
var count = categoryModel.ItemGroups.SelectMany(x => x.Items).Count();
```

The trick here is that SelectMany() flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence and project each element of the sequence.